# NodeJS - Copy and Rename all contents in existing directory recursively

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have a directory with folders and files within.  I want to copy the entire directory with all its contents to a different location while renaming all the files to something more meaningful.  I want to use nodejs to complete this series of operations.  What is an easy way to do it, other than moving it one by one and renaming it one by one?

Thanks.

-- Thanks for the comment!  So here is an example directory that I have in mind:

```
-MyFridge
 - MyFood.txt
  - MyApple.txt
  - MyOrange.txt
  - ...
 - MyDrinks
  - MySoda
    - MyDietCoke.txt
  - MyMilk.txt
  - ...
 - MyDesserts
 - MyIce
 ...
```

I want to replace "My" with "Tom," for instance, and I also would like to rename "My" to Tom in all the text files.  I am able to copy the directory to a different location using node-fs-extra, but I am having a hard time with renaming the file names.

Comment: You should post a sample file hierarchy so we can see the new filename mapping you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks!  I have already edited the post to give an example.

Comment: Start with the walk and fs libs and go from there.

Answer (score 6):

Define your own tools

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


function renameFilesRecursive(dir, from, to) {

   fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(it => {
     const itsPath = path.resolve(dir, it);
     const itsStat = fs.statSync(itsPath);

     if (itsPath.search(from) > -1) {
       fs.renameSync(itsPath, itsPath.replace(from, to))
     }

     if (itsStat.isDirectory()) {     
       renameFilesRecursive(itsPath.replace(from, to), from, to)
     } 
   })
}
```

Usage

```js
const dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app');

renameFilesRecursive(dir, /^My/, 'Tom');

renameFilesRecursive(dir, /\.txt$/, '.class');
```

Comment: In the example above the 'from' and 'to' parameters are not passed in the resursive call like this: renameFilesRecursive(itsPath, from, to)

Comment: @NielsBoogaard how to also place the renamed files into a new folder?

Comment: What would be the regex to rename any file names to i.txt? For example: a_1.txt, 22.txt, b.txt will become 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. I know for the I part, we need a counter; That's okay but, how to detect the files? I tried `/^.*\.txt$/` but didn't help. I got: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Images/1/10.jpg' -> '/ImagesAll/0.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

[fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) has a pretty nice API to deal with problems like that...

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

// Create two fs-jetpack contexts that point 
// to source and destination directories.
const src = jetpack.cwd("path/to/source/folder");
const dst = jetpack.cwd("path/to/destination");

// List all files (recursively) in the source directory.
src.find().forEach(path => {
  const content = src.read(path, "buffer");
  // Transform the path however you need...
  const transformedPath = path.replace("My", "Tom");
  // Write the file content under new name in the destination directory.
  dst.write(transformedPath, content);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P there you go.