# Rename files in sync from node js

Tags: node.js

I have some files that I need to copy in another folder and then renaming all of them one by one. Is there any solution to rename all those files in the new folder one by one in synchronous way?

Comment: Do you want something more than supplied in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714366/4636715 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you're looking for is

```
fs.renameSync(old_file_path, new_file_path)
```

You can find it in the node documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath)

Remember you'll need to require in filesystem with `const fs = require('fs')` as well.